# A regular expression that allow whitespace, coma , dot, numbers and any letters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My code:

```
if( preg_match( '/^[a-zA-Z0-9,.!? ]*$/', '.,!? a ' ) ) {
echo 'contains numbers, dot, coma, whitespace or latin letters<br/>'
}
```

But would be false if contains `žы`.

This

```
if ( preg_match("/^\p{L}+$/u", 'žы') ) {
echo 'Contains any letters<br/>';
}
```

How to combine both, so that allow any letters (also non latin), numbers, dot, coma, whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just combine them:

```
/^[,.!? \d\pL]*$/u
```